# Pivoting based on multiple columns and rearrange data in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have a python dataframe.

```
df1

Load           Instance_name            counter_name         counter_value
0              A                         bytes_read            0
0              A                         bytes_written         90
0              B                         bytes_read            100
0              B                         bytes_Written          90

1              A                         bytes_read            10
1              A                         bytes_written         940
1              B                         bytes_read            1100
1              B                         bytes_written         910
```

To simplify view, I need something like below ex. transform counter_name column fields to columns and rearrange data.***

```
df2 = 
Load     Instance_name  bytes_read     bytes_written   
0              A            0                    90       
0              B           100                   90
1              A            10                   940    
1              B           1100                  910
```

I am new to python dataframe libraries and not sure the right way to achieve this.

Comment: `df.pivot(index=['Load', 'Instance_name'], columns='counter_name', values='counter_value').reset_index()`

Comment: @mozway : I get the error../opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    297                         raise ValueError(
    298                             "Length of passed values is {val}, "
--> 299                             "index implies {ind}".format(val=len(data), ind=len(index))
    300                         )
    301                 except TypeError:

ValueError: Length of passed values is 264, index implies 2

Comment: Can you provide a dataframe constructor that reproduces this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.set_index(['Load', 'Instance_name', 'counter_name'])['counter_value'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
counter_name  Load Instance_name  bytes_Written  bytes_read  bytes_written
0                0             A            NaN         0.0           90.0
1                0             B           90.0       100.0            NaN
2                1             A            NaN        10.0          940.0
3                1             B            NaN      1100.0          910.0
```

Note typo in input dataframe bytes_Written and bytes_written.